# iPad specific button UX question (rating/feedback interaction system)

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, buttons, ipad, radio-buttons

TL;DR : how would you design better buttons than my 5 buttons for "I disagree" / Neutral / "I agree" feedback ?

I am doing an iPad application used by participants of an event during a presentation, for example a corporate seminar when CEO ask an audience of 300 managers some questions, to get qualitative audience feedback.

We already made:

- tweet-style Q&A where participants send messages and moderator select best quetsion
- digg-style Q&A where participants send messages, vote up/down quetsions and most popular ones are shown on big screen

Now we want to add a better ranking system that add more info, a 5 level scale

- I disagree
- I disagree somewhat
- Neutral
- I agree somewhat
- I agree

...
This way we will be able to determine

- "positive" answers, where most people agree
- "negative" answers where most people disagree
- "controversial" answers, where a certain amount agree and an other amount disagree

this would add more qualitative feedback for presentator, to get instant feedback during presentation, and later when exporting a detailed report.

My problem is how to translate this from a participant's user perspective ?
I am not happy with our buttons right now (mockup below)

Knowing that it is not tech-saavy users and we are on a somewhat new device, how would you design this interaction   ?

- the star rating system doesnt work as we are on a negative/neutral/positive scale
- having a cursor doesn't work well on iPad

(whole wireframe export is here http://cl.ly/46292f191Z11 )

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDhXIS.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical representation can work well; it doesn't require reading and has a big clickable area

[image]

Comment: The only issue I'd see with this is you could end up having a whole lot of faces on the page. You could work around this by visually de-emphasising the non-selected faces after a choice has been made on each line (but be careful to make sure the user knows they can still change their choice if they wish to)

Comment: Anna thanks, I think I'll go with this idea, and remove faces when line has been answered as @rsparis said.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, it seems, you don't really care about neutrality.

Then what about placing the default position to the middle? making it like "hot or cold" or something:

[image: agree-disagree potmeter]

This is based on a potmeter, it could be either dragged or just pointed to the right place.

Maybe this would be over-design, but the key point is that **if you don't care about the middle ground, just give that as default, and make people move into the direction which they like.**

(Also, since this is a tablet, make it draggable, I guess it'd fit the interface better)

In my country, hot is always at the left hand side when opening a tap, that's why hot is at left, but positive side is usually the right hand side, so it might be need to be turned around.

Comment: wow really quick, awesome.

This is a possibility, though I have 2 critics:

1/ I believe (maybe I am wrong) that using a cursor/potmeter is not so easy on a tablet.
This is why i was looking for an alternative UX solution.

2/ What if I want to set the feedback as "neutral" ? we would then need a "skip this answer" checkbox or something, which is an other step and annoying

Comment: OK, well, if you want 5 discrete options, use radio buttons or something similar click-based selection, making sure the target area is large enough (look at Fitt's law) https://dl.getdropbox.com/u/7067930/checkboxes_heat.png - perhaps using background colors. BTW, sliding works perfectly well in a touch device, esp. a tablet, try it out: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/forms/slider/

Comment: From my experience for our target audience (non tech saavy middle aged people that mostly never used a tablet before this app) tapping is easier than using sliders, so I will stick to the radio buttons with a face shape. Thanks for your help!